# Error C2078: too many initializers

Tags: c++, c, function, compiler-errors

Why does this code not work? My IDE is Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <stdio.h>
float tempatureGuide(float F, float C);
#define FREEZING_PT 32.0f
#define SCALE_FACTOR (5.0f/9.0f)
int main(void)
{
    float fahrenheit = 0.0;
    float celsius = 0.0 ;
    int convertTemp;
    printf ("Enter 0 to calculate Celsius or 1 to calculate Fahrenheit:            ");
    scanf ("%d", &convertTemp);

    if (convertTemp == 0)
    {
        // compute Celsius
        printf("Enter Fahrenheit temperture: ");
        scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
        celsius = ((fahrenheit - FREEZING_PT) * SCALE_FACTOR);
        printf("Fahrenheit = %f  and Celsius = %f\n", fahrenheit, celsius);
        float tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);  // Error here
    }
    else
    {
        // compute fahrenheit
        printf("Enter the temperature in degrees fahrenheit\n\n");
        scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
        celsius = (SCALE_FACTOR)* (fahrenheit - FREEZING_PT);
        printf("The converted temperature is %f", celsius);
        float tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);    // and here

    }
    return (0);
}

float tempatureGuide(float F, float C){
    if (F < 32 || C < 0)
        printf("It is freezing!");
    else if (F <= 60 || C <= 16)
        printf("It is cold");
    else if (F >= 70 || C >= 21)
        printf("It is just right");
    else if (F >= 82 || C >= 28)
        printf("It is warm");
    else if (F > 95 || C > 35)
        printf("It is hot");
    else
        printf("Please enter a number!");
    return (0);
}
```

The goal here is to add to the converting temperature project I did earlier and add an `if else` statement function to it that comments on the temp. The error I get is

```
Error   3   error C2078: too many initializes
```

on both the lines where I call my function. I searched for an answer but couldn't find any.

Comment: Fix your indents. And `float tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);` is not how you call a function.

Comment: I've removed some irrelevant text from your question. I've also indented some of the code so it's shown as code -- but the code layout is still badly in need of improvement. *Consistent* indentation makes code much easier to read. There's a typo in the error message; you should copy-and-paste the exact error message into your question. C and C++ are two different languages; which one are you using? Your code looks like it's probably valid as either, but the error message makes me think you're compiling it with a C++ compiler. If you're programming C, configure your IDE to compile C.

Comment: Note that a temperature of 100 C or 212 F will be reported as "It is just right" because you switched from `<` or `<=` to `>=`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will try to indent better from now on. I am using C not C++ ill change my compiler to C.

Answer (score 3):

This line looks like an attempt at a C++ initialization of a `float` with one too many arguments (hence the "*too many initializers*" error), not like a function call.

```
float tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);
```

Presumably you want to call the function and store the result in a variable:

```
float temp = tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);
```

Or just call the function and ignore the return value:

```
tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);
```

Especially since your function always returns `0`, so one might question the need for a non-void return type.

Comment: Wow thank you I see what i did wrong now that was so much help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a function

```
float tempatureGuide(float fahrenheit, float celsius) { //...}
```

as

```
float retval = tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);
```

or least

```
tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);  // not need to use return value
```

Only.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry Did a copy paste error in hurry!

Comment: @juanchopanza should be fine now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is just a simple error. Please change 2 lines of code where you are calling tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius); function as follows.

```
float tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius); --> float ret = tempatureGuide(fahrenheit, celsius);
```

I tested the same in my VS2013 as you are using the same with the mentioned changes. I am able to compile and run it successfully. See the attachment.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't really add any useful information to what is already there in the other answers.

Comment: This is a justification answer that his code works fine with the mentioned changes.! Thats why added a screenshot as well. !

Comment: Screenshots are rarely useful. You don't have to *prove* that it works; we'll take your word for it (or complain if it doesn't).

Answer (score -1):

Just call the function and return it to a variable of the same type.

Comment: An example would be great here.